# Pre-defined XAML code for new control that is added in VS designer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, xaml

Is there a way to automatically generate XAML code when you drop your control from toolbox to designer? I.e. it would create certain objects (nested properties) automatically and user would not have to type the same code every time to set certain (nested) properties. Kind of a template XAML code that is pre-defined by control's developer.

I'm pretty new to WPF so I'm wondering why there aren't any nested properties in the controls that are in Visual Studio's toolbox (button, label etc...)? Are attached properties a cure for this or have they just cut corners when designing WPF. :)

The problem is that my control (WinForms style property hierarchy) has nested properties and if I "internally" in my code create objects for those properties then XAML does not reflect the situation because it does not have any elements that match the current situation (i.e. the objects created in my control's constructor).

Is the only solution to leave all the properties null and let the user create them all? That way it seems to work correctly but user has to write many lines of XAML to reflect the situation in WinForms.

Comment: -1. Wall of text and not a single line of code. BTW, while winforms is completely useless and requires a bunch of horrible hacks for anything, WPF has these feature called [`Styling and Templating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx) which can be used to define Application-wide settings for individual UI elements (such as setting properties, colors and the like). Don't try to fit winforms hacks into WPF, they're not needed nor desired.

Comment: Any chance you could give any actual help rather down down-voting and bad-mouthing WinForms. You seem to be the kind of person who has no real experience in real programming languages like C/C++ or assembly and who like those "higher level" tools like WPF and LabView. Your comment is completely useless. Sorry to burst your bubble. It's a shame you cannot down-vote comments. That's probably the reason you commented...

Comment: sorry, I have no experience in C++, however that doesn't make your question any better. You should post the relevant code of your attempted solution, see [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before posting questions in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality that you seek is not available via any of the controls in WPF. However, Visual Studio used to have Macros that would enable us to add pre-written sections of code into our pages, but unfortunately, they decided to remove that great functionality. Fortunately, they have introduced [Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx) as a partial alternative.

Unfortunately again, these Code Snippets don't work in XAML pages, but once again fortunately, there are a few Visual Studio add ins that will enable you to enter pre-written XAML into your pages at the click of a button on the Code Plex website:

[XAML Code Snippets addin for Visual Studio 2010](http://xamlcodesnippets.codeplex.com/)
[XAML Snippets for Visual Studio](http://xamlsnippets.codeplex.com/)

Please try using one of the above add ins to see if they meet your needs.